# How to play back multiple 4K videos with resizing and cropping

Tags: video, directx12

I'm looking for playing multiple videos (source HD and 4k, 10 bits), between 3 and 12+ videos, which could be cropped and resized, and those be adjusted on the fly (as videos are being played), sent to a 10 bits 4k DX12 buffer (or up to 8k).

The resulting buffer is meant to be used for display or rendering (ie., exporting and encoding the result into a file, which could be h264 h265 or something else).

I'm planning to instantiate multiple [DX12 decoders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/direct3d-12-video-overview), then crop the buffers/textures, then send with a certain size and orientation the video buffers/textures onto a final 10 bits buffer/texture. I did few things with DX12, but it's not clear how I should do the crop, position resize and final merge in terms of objects and code.

How should I do the crop, resize, and placement so it can be adjusted on the fly?

Comment: This isn't something someone would want to do in a game, right? why waste time and memory displaying 12x 4k videos when nobody has a 12x4k monitor?

Comment: @user253751 Off topic.

Comment: If it's not about games, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @user253751 It is. No problem.

Comment: if it is about games, why do you design your game this way when nobody has a 12x4k monitor?

Comment: @user253751 The final display will be 4k-8k. The inputs will be 2k-4k. As stated in the OP.